# JavaScript/HTML Canvas: mouse detection for looped row of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas, mouse

I'm building a simple drum machine that uses canvas for the GUI. I have a row of buttons drawn with a for loop that toggle on/off when clicked.

[Here's a sample on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt2qhf1n/)

While it works, I'm a bit embarrassed by my `buttonToggleDetection` function. It's the only solution I could think of to check which button the mouse is over. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better way to do this?

```
var buttonToggleDetection = function(posx, posy, x) {

    if (posx < canvas.width/2 && posy > x && posy < x*2) {

        if (posx > x*1 && posx < x*2) {
            if (pattern[0] === 0) {
                pattern[0] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[0] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*2 && posx < x*3) {
            if (pattern[1] === 0) {
                pattern[1] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[1] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*3 && posx < x*4) {
            if (pattern[2] === 0) {
                pattern[2] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[2] = 0;
            }
        } 
        else if (posx > x*4 && posx < x*5) {
            if (pattern[3] === 0) {
                pattern[3] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[3] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*5 && posx < x*6) {
            if (pattern[4] === 0) {
                pattern[4] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[4] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*6 && posx < x*7) {
            if (pattern[5] === 0) {
                pattern[5] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[5] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*7 && posx < x*8) {
            if (pattern[6] === 0) {
                pattern[6] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[6] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*8 && posx < x*9) {
            if (pattern[7] === 0) {
                pattern[7] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[7] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (posx > canvas.width/2 && posy > x && posy < x*2) {

        if (posx > x*9 && posx < x*10) {
            if (pattern[8] === 0) {
                pattern[8] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[8] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*10 && posx < x*11) {
            if (pattern[9] === 0) {
                pattern[9] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[9] = 0;
            }
        } 
        else if (posx > x*11 && posx < x*12) {
            if (pattern[10] === 0) {
                pattern[10] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[10] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*12 && posx < x*13) {
            if (pattern[11] === 0) {
                pattern[11] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[11] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*13 && posx < x*14) {
            if (pattern[12] === 0) {
                pattern[12] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[12] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*14 && posx < x*15) {
            if (pattern[13] === 0) {
                pattern[13] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[13] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*15 && posx < x*16) {
            if (pattern[14] === 0) {
                pattern[14] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[14] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (posx > x*16 && posx < x*17) {
            if (pattern[15] === 0) {
                pattern[15] = 1;
            } else {
                pattern[15] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This post would be better posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Scriptable: IMHO, the question seems ok for Stackoverflow  as well as codereview. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of bounds checking the buttons seems fine...but your loop could be tightened up a bit by defining your buttons in an array and then looping through that array.

Here's one way to draw and toggle buttons in html canvas:

[image]
[image]

- Define each of your button's x,y,width,height & pressed-state

  ```
  var buttons=[];
  buttons.push({x:20,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'One',isPressed:false});
  buttons.push({x:80,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'Two',isPressed:true});
  buttons.push({x:140,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'Three',isPressed:false});
  ```
- Test if the mouse is over any button:

  ```
  for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
      var b=buttons[i];
      if(mx>b.x && mx<b.x+b.width && my>b.y && my<=b.y+b.height){
          b.isPressed=(!b.isPressed);
      }
  }
  ```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.font='14px verdana';

var buttons=[];
buttons.push({x:20,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'One',isPressed:false});
buttons.push({x:80,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'Two',isPressed:true});
buttons.push({x:140,y:20,width:50,height:35,text:'Three',isPressed:false});

draw();

function draw(){
  var label;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    var b=buttons[i];
    if(b.isPressed){
      ctx.shadowBlur=0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX=0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY=0;
      ctx.shadowColor=null;
      ctx.fillStyle='powderblue';
      label='ON';
    }else{
      ctx.shadowBlur=2;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX=2;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY=2;
      ctx.shadowColor='black';
      ctx.fillStyle='paleturquoise';
      label='OFF';
    }
    ctx.strokeRect(b.x,b.y,b.width,b.height);
    ctx.fillRect(b.x,b.y,b.width,b.height);
    ctx.shadowBlur=0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX=0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY=0;
    ctx.shadowColor=null;
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillText(label,b.x+b.width/2,b.y+b.height/2);
    ctx.fillStyle='gray';
    ctx.fillText(label,b.x+b.width/2+1,b.y+b.height/2+1);
  }
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // 
  for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    var b=buttons[i];
    if(mx>b.x && mx<b.x+b.width && my>b.y && my<=b.y+b.height){
      b.isPressed=(!b.isPressed);
    }
  }
  draw();

}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click the buttons</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using svg instead of canvas. The content of an SVG node is very similar to that of a canvas node, but each shape is built out of XML markup or dynamically created elements, much like document.body's contents. This gives you a few big advantages:

1. You can apply classes to individual shapes, and use css to apply
   colors/styles.
2. You can take advantage of css's :hover pseudo-style
   to apply color to hovered elements.
3. Most importantly: *You can bind events to each shape!*

**The code below is available to fiddle with at http://jsfiddle.net/3zevLyur/1/**

Here's the html:

```
<svg id="drumMachine"/>
<div id="debugText"/>
```

Here's the javascript to build the pads and bind events:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("drumMachine");
var activePad = null;
var debugText = document.getElementById("debugText");

for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    createNewPad(x);
}


function createNewPad(padNumber) {
    var r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect")
    r.setAttribute("width", "40");
    r.setAttribute("height", "40");
    r.setAttribute("x", padNumber * 50);
    r.setAttribute("data-pad-number", x);
    r.onmouseenter = mouseOver;
    r.onmouseleave = mouseOut;
    svg.appendChild(r);
}

function mouseOver() {
    activePad = this;
    debugText.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-pad-number");
}

function mouseOut() {
    activePad = null;
    debugText.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the canvas element, so maybe you can bind events to a canvas' children, too. If that's the case, you can do that inside the for loop where you create the pads

Comment: HEre's a fiddle that lets you toggle on/off state: http://jsfiddle.net/c0spb72v/1/